# Is there a way to include all dependencies from a jar?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, discord-jda

Ok, so I have modified an old project to use a new version of JDA (Java Discord API). It builds fine but at runtime, it gives errors of missing classes. Also, I know that my level of knowledge in Java is poor. Don't just tell me that I should go learn more. The Gradle version for this project is 2.7(I know this is old, if I need to update it please give me directions to do so).

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name "forge"
            url "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/"
        }
        maven {
            name "sonatype"
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}

apply plugin: "forge"

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

version = mc_version + "-" + mod_version

archivesBaseName = "DiscordChat"

minecraft {
    version = mc_version + "-" + forge_version
    runDir = "run"

    mappings = mcp_mappings

    replaceIn "OneSevenTenMod.java"
    replace "@VERSION@", mod_version

    srgExtra "PK: com/iwebpp/crypto net/shadowfacts/discordchat/repack/com/iwebpp/crypto"
    srgExtra "PK: com/neovisionaries/ws/client net/shadowfacts/discordchat/repack/com/neovisionaries/ws/client"
    srgExtra "PK: com/sun/jna net/shadowfacts/discordchat/repack/com/sun/jna"
    srgExtra "PK: com/vdurmont/emoji net/shadowfacts/discordchat/repack/com/vdurmont/emoji"
    srgExtra "PK: gnu/trove net/shadowfacts/discordchat/repack/gnu/trove"
    srgExtra "PK: net/dv8tion/jda net/shadowfacts/discordchat/repack/net/dv8tion/jda"
    srgExtra "PK: okhttp3 net/shadowfacts/discordchat/repack/okhttp3"
    srgExtra "PK: okio net/shadowfacts/discordchat/repack/okio"
    srgExtra "PK: org/apache/commons/collections4 net/shadowfacts/discordchat/repack/org/apache/commons/collections4"
    srgExtra "PK: org/apache/commons/lang3 net/shadowfacts/discordchat/repack/org/apache/commons/lang3"
    srgExtra "PK: org/json net/shadowfacts/discordchat/repack/org/json"
    srgExtra "PK: tomp2p/opuswrapper net/shadowfacts/discordchat/repack/tomp2p/opuswrapper"
}

processResources {
    inputs.property "version", project.version
    inputs.property "mcversion", project.minecraft.version

    from (sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include "mcmod.info"
        expand "version": project.version, "mcversion": project.minecraft.version
    }
    from (sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude "mcmod.info"
    }
}

configurations {
    shade
    compile.extendsFrom shade
}

repositories {
    maven {
        name "shadowfacts"
        url "http://maven.shadowfacts.net/"
    }
    flatDir {
        dirs "../core/libs"
    }
}

dependencies {
    shade project(":core")
}

jar {
    configurations.shade.each { dep ->
        from (project.zipTree(dep)) {
            exclude "META-INF", "META-INF/**"
        }
    }
}
```

errors:

```
Exception in thread "DiscordChat-initializer" [12:02:49] [DiscordChat-initializer/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:749]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
[12:02:49] [DiscordChat-initializer/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:749]:       at net.shadowfacts.discordchat.repack.net.dv8tion.jda.internal.utils.JDALogger.<clinit>(JDALogger.java:69)
[12:02:49] [DiscordChat-initializer/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:749]:       at net.shadowfacts.discordchat.repack.net.dv8tion.jda.internal.utils.IOUtil.<clinit>(IOUtil.java:35)
[12:02:49] [DiscordChat-initializer/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:749]:       at net.shadowfacts.discordchat.repack.net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder.build(JDABuilder.java:1741)
[12:02:49] [DiscordChat-initializer/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:749]:       at net.shadowfacts.discordchat.core.DiscordChat.lambda$connect$0(DiscordChat.java:90)
[12:02:49] [DiscordChat-initializer/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:749]:       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
[12:02:49] [DiscordChat-initializer/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:749]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
[12:02:49] [DiscordChat-initializer/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:749]:       at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:101)
[12:02:49] [DiscordChat-initializer/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:749]:       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
[12:02:49] [DiscordChat-initializer/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:749]:       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
[12:02:49] [DiscordChat-initializer/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:749]:       ... 5 more
```

Comment: 1) shade plugin does what you're asking 2) You have no Slf4j dependencies

Comment: @OneCricketeer doesn't the shade plugin start at gradle 5.0?

Comment: Maybe, but that's not the problem. You'll want to add `implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.36'` in the `dependencies` block for your particular error message, assuming you don't already have Slf4j jars in core/libs